# Connections, edges, node: how to use a subtype of a node

Tags: graphql

I'm following the Connection, Edges, Node, concept of relay in Apollo.
I use a `Node { id: ID! }` interface. I have a collection of entities that are all kind of 'groups', with small differences. I would like to model these as a single Connection, but not really sure how to do that:

```
     # simplified for example
    interface Group {
        id: ID!
        type: String!
    }
    type WallGroup implements Node & Group {
        id: ID!
        type: String!
    }
    type Event implements Node & Group {
        id: ID!
        type: String!
        dteStart: DateTime!
        dteEnd: DateTime!
    }
    type GroupEdge implements Edge {
        cursor: String!
        node: Group!
    }
    type GroupConnection implements Connection {
        edges: [GroupEdge!]!
        pageInfo: PageInfo!
        totalCount: Int!
    }
```

This will generate an error because `GroupEdge` expects node to a `Node`. It is, but the `Group` interface is not and it therefore fails.

Another thing I tried was

```
    union AllGroup = WallGroup | Event
    type GroupEdge implements Edge {
        cursor: String!
        node: AllGroup!
    }
```

But this leads to the same issue. Apparently, the union loses notion of the Node interface implemented on `WallGroup` and `Event`.

Any ideas on hwo to model this or should I just duplicate everything?

Answer (score 0):

The [Relay specification](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/en/graphql-server-specification.html) only requires that your schema include a `Node` interface -- when creating a Relay-compliant, normally you don't create interfaces for Connection and Edge.

The reason Relay requires a `Node` interface is to allow us to query for any `Node` by id. However, typically there's no need for a field that returns one of many edges or one of many connections. Therefore, typically there's no need to need to make an interface for edges or connections. This is what you would normally do:

```
interface Node {
  id: ID!
}

interface Group {
    id: ID!
    type: String!
}

type GroupA implements Node & Group {
    id: ID!
    type: String!
    # other fields
}

type GroupA implements Node & Group {
    id: ID!
    type: String!
    # other fields
}

type GroupEdge {
    cursor: String!
    node: Group!
}

type GroupConnection {
    edges: [GroupEdge!]!
    pageInfo: PageInfo!
    totalCount: Int!
}
```

According to the [spec](https://facebook.github.io/graphql/June2018/#sec-Objects), "the [implementing] object type must include a field of the same name for every field defined in an interface." So, if an interface specifies that a field is of the type `Foo`, an implementing type cannot have the field be of type `FooBar` even if `Foo` is an interface and `FooBar` implements it. Unfortunately, that means it's not really possible to use interfaces like you're trying to do.

If you would like to utilize interfaces to provide a safety-net of sorts and ensure that the implementing types are consistent, you ***can*** do something like this:

```
interface Connection {
  pageInfo: PageInfo!
  # don't specify edges
}

interface Edge {
  cursor: String!
  # don't specify node
}
```

This way you can ensure that fields like `pageInfo` or `cursor` are present in the implementing types, have the correct type and are non-null. But this kind of schema-level validation is really the only benefit you get out adding and implementing these two interfaces.

Comment: The first approach is how I implemented it, I think. This is the error: `Interface field Edge.node expects type Node! but GroupEdge.node is type Group!.`

`interface Connection { edges: [Edge!]! pageInfo: PageInfo! totalCount: Int! }` 

`interface Edge { cursor: String! node: Node! }`

[sorry, formatting this comment didn't work]

Comment: That error indicates you're still using an interface for your edge, so I don't believe you implemented it as suggested.